cannot get SQL join clause ON to align with sqlfluff
I am trying to get sqlfluff to perform various alignments within our company's SQL code.  The one I'm struggling with is the alignment within the join clause
For example, code as written:
select *
from table_1
    join table_2      alias     on table_1.key = alias.key
    join table_3  alias3 on table_1.key = alias3.key

SQL fluff output
select *
from table_1
    join table_2    alias on table_1.key = alias.key
    join table_3    alias3 on table_1.key = alias3.key

Desired output
select *
from table_1
    join table_2    alias    on table_1.key = alias.key
    join table_3    alias3   on table_1.key = alias3.key

It seems like this should be possible, but I cannot figure out what the name of the ON portion of the join is called in the sqlfluff config (if it exists).
for example
[sqlfluff:layout:type:alias_expression]
spacing_before = align
align_within = statement
align_scope = bracketed

works to align the alias but the ON portion of the join begins a single space after the alias.  What I would like to have happen is the table alias and ON portion to be aligned independently.  I can't figure out what the right component name within the [sqlfluff:layout:type: portion of the config is.  If anyone knows where to look for the full list of options or has a suggestion on this one I'd much appreciate it.  Thanks.
